# Оптимизация кода 2

Tags: mysql

т.к. в старой теме достиг предела коментариев, начну заново с более легким вопросом:
есть таблица областей и городов, если это область то obl_id=0, если город то obl_id указывает в какой это области

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `obl` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`obl_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

INSERT INTO `obl` (`id`, `name`, `obl_id`) VALUES
(2, 'Московская', 0),
(4, 'Москва', 2),
(8, 'Киев', 6),
(6, 'Киевская', 0);
```

есть таблица юзеров, sub_obl показывает на что подписался юзер

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`sub_obl` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

INSERT INTO `user` (`uid`, `email`, `sub_obl`) VALUES
(1, 'юзер1', 2),
(2, 'юзер2', 8),
(3, 'юзер3', 999);
```

есть таблица новостей, n_obl указывает к какому городу или к какой отрасли относится новость

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topic` (
`nid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`news` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`n_obl` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

INSERT INTO `topic` (`nid`, `news`, `n_obl`) VALUES
(1, 'news1', 2),
(2, 'news2', 4),
(3, 'news3', 8),
(4, 'news4', 999);
```

смотрим глазами юзера:
1. если подписка на город, то получать только город
2. если подписка на область, то получать новости области и с городов этой области
3. если подписка на все, то получать все новости

смотрим глазами редактора:
1. если новость по городу то получать ее должны и те кто подписался на этот город и те кто подписался на новости этой области и те кто подписался на все новсти
2. если новость по области то получать ее должны те кто подписался на города этой области, на эту область и все
3. если новость для всех, то получать ее должны все =)

конечный результат:

1|юзер1|2 - 1|news1|2
1|юзер1|2 - 2|news2|4
1|юзер1|2 - 4|news4|all

2|юзер2|8 - 3|news3|8
2|юзер2|8 - 4|news4|all

3|юзер3|all - 1|news1|2
3|юзер3|all - 2|news2|4
3|юзер3|all - 3|news3|8
3|юзер3|all - 4|news4|all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё тоже решение, и верный ответ:

```
select *
from
  (
    select 1 as uid, 'юзер1' as email, 2 as sub_obl
    union all select 2, 'юзер2', 8
    union all select 3, 'юзер3', 999
  ) u,
  (
    select 1 as nid, 'news1' as news, 2 as n_obl
    union all select 2, 'news2', 4
    union all select 3, 'news3', 8
    union all select 4, 'news4', 999
  ) t
where
  999 in ( u.sub_obl, t.n_obl ) or
  t.n_obl = u.sub_obl or
  exists (
    select 1
    from
      (
        select 2 as id, 'Московская' as name, 0 as obl_id
        union all select 4, 'Москва', 2
        union all select 8, 'Киев', 6
        union all select 6, 'Киевская', 0
      ) obl
    where
      (
        obl.id = t.n_obl and
        obl.obl_id = u.sub_obl
      ) or
      (
        obl.id = u.sub_obl and
        obl.obl_id = t.n_obl
      )
  )
```

Либо на живой базе:

```
select *
from
  user u,
  topic t
where
  999 in ( u.sub_obl, t.n_obl ) or
  t.n_obl = u.sub_obl or
  exists (
    select 1
    from
      obl
    where
      (
        obl.id = t.n_obl and
        obl.obl_id = u.sub_obl
      ) or
      (
        obl.id = u.sub_obl and
        obl.obl_id = t.n_obl
      )
  )
```

Comment: вообщем то гениально!
только пока разобрал код, пока вкурил про exists =))
одно только Вы пропустили, вот код подредактированный:
    SELECT * FROM user u, topic t  
     WHERE t.n_obl = u.sub_obl OR 999 IN (u.sub_obl, t.n_obl) 
     OR EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 from obl WHERE
     ( obl.id = t.n_obl and obl.obl_id = u.sub_obl )
     OR
     ( u.sub_obl = obl.id and obl.obl_id = t.n_obl )
     )

Comment: Да) Про областную новость - не догадался)

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку в Вашем вопросе я не нашел ни единого вопросительного знака, то ограничусь лишь замечаниями о Вашей схеме.

1. Мне кажется, что иерархические таблицы - типа "Область-Город" следует строить, когда предполагаемая иерархия не до конца понятна разработчику. В вашем случае это не так.
2. Но раз уж так случилось, необходимо obl_id сделать внешним ключом, по отношению к собственной таблице.
3. То же самое относится ко всем остальным таблицам. Они, сироты, ни одна не имеют родителя, хотя должны его иметь.

Вот пока и все.